# How to customize Knowledge Article votes

Tags: knowledge

Is it possible to customize voting for Knowledge Articles?  Client request is to only allow two choices ("Was this helpful?  Yes/No") instead of 5 star ratings.  I have not found any platform feature to customize the scale, so I'm looking into creating votes directly (assigning numbers to Yes/No).  The articles are displayed in a custom VF page already, so a custom "Was this helpful" control is no problem.  But I can't find a way to record votes.  `KnowledgeArticleVoteStat` (and the related `<articleType>__VoteStat`) are read only.  I cannot find API documentation for recording votes.  Is this not possible, or have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the answer.  Although the [documentation on the Vote object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_vote.htm) only mentions recording votes for Ideas and Replies, [this data model diagram](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm) shows that Votes can apply to Articles as well.  Trying to query for all Votes returns an interesting error message; apparently you can only query votes with certain filtering applied.  I have confirmed, however, that I can create votes, at least for the current user.  The voting user is recorded by the CreatedById, so it doesn't look like you can record votes for other users (which is fine for my purposes).